# DLL injection and ejection from .NET Framework 4.8 app

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, dll, code-injection

I'm injecting DLL into the WPF process using an Injector from [snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) or [Reloaded.Injector](https://github.com/Reloaded-Project/Reloaded.Injector).
Injected DLL is .net 4.8 class library.

The injection works, but ejection - does not. My library is still locked by the target process after ejection. Is it possible to unload it at all?

I've tried `FreeLibrary` and `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` with no success. [Reloaded.Injector](https://github.com/Reloaded-Project/Reloaded.Injector) `Eject()` function returns true, but DLL is still locked.

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("ModsOptimizer").FirstOrDefault();
_injector = new Injector(process);
_injectionDllPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Injection.dll");
var address = _injector.Inject(_injectionDllPath);
_injector.CallFunction(_injectionDllPath, "Spam", default);
_injector.Eject(_injectionDllPath);
```

Comment: Are you sure that dll wasn't in use before inject? Try to set breakpoint on ```_injectionDllPath =...``` and manually delete the file

Comment: @AndriiKhomiak, thanks for asking. I have checked and I can delete DLL before `_injectionDllPath =...`